# Problem with the height from bootstrap select

Tags: html, asp.net, bootstrap-5, razor-pages, bootstrap-selectpicker

[image]

I can't change the height from the dropdown list.

I use Bootstrap-select 1.13.1.

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" id="projectSelect" name="projectSelect" onchange="this.form.submit()" data-width="400px">
@foreach (var project in Model.ProjectList)
{
    @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.selectedProject) && Model.selectedProject.Equals(project))
    {
    <option style="height:35px" value="@project" selected>@project</option>
    }
    <option style="height:35px" value="@project">@project</option>
}
</select>
<select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" id="ticketSelect" name="ticketSelect" onchange="this.form.submit()" data-width="400px">
@foreach (var ticket in Model.IssueList)
{
    @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.selectedIssue) && Model.selectedIssue.Equals(ticket))
    {
        <option value="@ticket" selected>@ticket</option>
    }
    <option value="@ticket">@ticket</option>
}
</select>
```

Comment: An `option` does not have a height, you have to set it on the `select`

Comment: but probably the problem comes from the container you are using to wrap those 2 selects and you didn't include it in your snippet. Can you please share a working example showing the dropdowns appearing with the wrong height? because otherwise is not possible to reproduce the problem you are seeing. Don't forget to include the correct cdn assets.. but I still suspects it's not a matter of bootstrap-select itself because I tried your code and there's no height issue as you showed in those pictures